# Работа с библиотекой geocoder

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps-api

Исходная задача. Есть широта и долгота. Надо получить адрес, страна, город, область и пр.
Использую библиотеку geocoder.
в режиме дебага посмотрел, куда обращается geocoder при выполнении. он дает запрос в гугл. Возможно, тут причина.
API key гугл я сделал. Карты две подключил. Для всех карт один API key.

```
import geocoder

api_key = 'api_key'
g = geocoder.google([45.15, -75.14], method='reverse', key=api_key)

print(str(g.ok)) #False возвращает.
```

Посмотрел, что вызывает при создании g
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Решили отладить? :) Там кст написано про `error`: `REQUEST_DENIED`

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<[REQUEST_DENIED] Google - Geocode [empty]>` - некорректный api_key, с действительныи ключом работает:

```
import geocoder

api_key = 'my_api_key'
g = geocoder.google([45.15, -75.14], method='reverse', key=api_key)
```

в g:

```
>>> g
<[OK] Google - Reverse #9 results>
>>> g.status
'OK'
```

результаты:

```
for r in g:
    print(r)

[14634 Concession Rd 4, Berwick, ON K0C 1G0, Canada]
[14634 Concession Rd 4, Berwick, ON K0C 1G0, Canada]
[Berwick, ON K0C 1G0, Canada]
[North Stormont, ON, Canada]
[Ontario K0C, Canada]
[Stormont, Dundas and Glengarry United Counties, ON, Canada]
[Ontario, Canada]
[Canada]
[5V25+2X North Stormont, ON, Canada]
```

Comment: Надо было Billing подключить в гугл аккаунте. заработало после этого.